# nginx: Your request contains duplicate headers. error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have multiple websites hosted on an ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (focal) using nginx 1.18.0.
2 of the websites have this issue.
The website build files are in a aws S3 bucket and the nginx is used to serve them using proxy_pass.
accessing the website from the aws link works fine:
http://sub.exanple.net.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
few days ago I started getting the following error when accessing from my link (not was s3 bucket):

```
<Error>
  <Code>DuplicateHeaderName</Code>
  <Message>Your request contains duplicate headers.</Message>
  <RequestId>ECF9EYBG9JYDKY3W</RequestId>
  <HostId>9RZva0WYEYGtcoWadqm3MrOOqFhiWLwS6Ax8YwMStzz3pdW1rqNkKcPxszT9ENcODGlKyoqfBXw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

here is the website config file:
I changed the actual link to sub.example.net

```
root /var/www/sub.example.net/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name sub.example.net;
    
        location / {
               # proxy_set_header Connection "";
               # proxy_set_header Authorization '';
                proxy_set_header Host sub.example.net.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com;
               # proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
               # proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
               # proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
               # proxy_hide_header x-amz-server-side-encryption;
               # proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
               # proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
               # proxy_intercept_errors on;
               # add_header Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_pass http://sub.example.net.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/;
        }
    
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

Response Headers:

```
content-type: application/xml
date: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 04:30:08 GMT
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
x-amz-id-2: 9RZva0WYEYGtcoWadqm3MrOOqFhiWLwS6Ax8YwMStzz3pdW1rqNkKcPxszT9ENcODGlKyoqfBXw=
x-amz-request-id: ECF9EYBG9JYDKY3W
```

Request Headers:
I changed the link in authority header only the rest are exactly the same.

```
:authority: sub.example.net 
:method: GET
:path: /?sid=06de736ae4e63d2a700f0bf7ec38&user=atsuae&lang=en&b=prestable&v=1.51
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1073658407.1674799704; _ga_L6NP7TDMF6=GS1.1.1675855157.3.1.1675856361.0.0.0
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

I tried restarting the server and running `nginx -t`.

if anyone can direct me to were the issue is or how to find it I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by commenting

```
# proxy_set_header Host $host;
```